# Include JavaScript in Perl-CGI generated page

Tags: javascript, html, perl, include, cgi

I was trying to add a java-script to a page which is generated on the fly.
I tried this, but it seems like it is not working.

```
<SCRIPT SRC=\"sorttable.js\"></SCRIPT>
```

I always have to inline javacode along with the html for it to work.
Any clues ?

Comment: Is the code not executing or is the code not printing?  If it's printing but not executing, don't forget to add the type attribute [type="text/javascript"] to the script element.

Comment: What is the page generated code ?

Answer (score 4):

`qq()` is the equivalent of `""`, but with matching delimiters.  It is going to be your friend if you are outputing HTML or JavaScript.

```
print qq(<script type="text/javascript">alert("The world is my oyster");</script>);
```

Note that you don't have to use `()` as delimiters, see [perlop](http://p3rl.org/op#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

If you are outputting JavaScript that is building HTML, you should be using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Ext](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/).  But either way you will be in the multiple-levels-of-escaping-hell.  [JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/JSON%3a%3aXS) might make your life less painful.  Also learn about [here-documents](http://p3rl.org/op#%3c%3cEOF):

```
my $js = <<'JS';
    alert( 'The world is my oyster' );
    var $href = "example.html";
    document.write( '<a href="' + $href + '">clicky</a>' );
JS
print qq(<script type="text/javascript">$js</script>);
```

The tricky bit about the above is that `$href` is a JavaScript variable, not a Perl variable.  (Yes, JS identifiers may include `$`.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this link might be helpful:
http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/cgi_form.html

It provides method of embedding a jsp function into the form-onsubmit as follow:

> print $q->start_form(
>         -name    => 'main_form',
>         -method  => 'GET',
>         -enctype => &CGI::URL_ENCODED,
>
> ```
>   -onsubmit => 'return javascript:validation_function()',
>   -action => '/where/your/form/gets/sent',   );
> ```

And there is a following link from Perl5 CGI library - support for Javascript, it's about linking javascript function to an event.
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.60/cgi_docs.html#javascripting

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on your quoting structure for the *WHOLE* thing. If you're printing this out in a uninterpolated *heredoc*, then `\"` just creates a bigger problem.

```
   print <<'END_HTML';
   ...
      <SCRIPT SRC=\"sorttable.js\"></SCRIPT>
   ...
   END_HTML
```

or a q expression:

```
  print q~
   ...
      <SCRIPT SRC=\"sorttable.js\"></SCRIPT>
   ...
   ~;
```

So you would have to show more of your context. But let me assure you: when I write out the tags the right way, my JavaScript files gets sourced into the page, just as I would expect.