# Getting error in perl Can't find string terminator "EOF" anywhere before EOF at /var/www/sandeep/testeof.cgi line 2

Tags: perl

iam using perl to print some data but it is giving me error as *Can't find string terminator "EOF" anywhere before EOF at*

**The code is:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
print <<EOF;
hello
EOF
```

**ERROR:**

> [Mon May 23 11:32:12 2016] [error] [client 192.168.10.117] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/, referer: http://192.168.10.100/
>   [Mon May 23 11:32:12 2016] [error] [client 192.168.10.117] malformed header from script. Bad header=hello: testeof.cgi
>   [Mon May 23 11:32:18 2016] [error] [client 192.168.10.117] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/, referer: http://192.168.10.100/
>   [Mon May 23 11:32:18 2016] [error] [client 192.168.10.117] Can't find string terminator "EOF" anywhere before EOF at /var/www/sandeep/testeof.cgi line 2.
>   [Mon May 23 11:32:18 2016] [error] [client 192.168.10.117] Premature end of script headers: testeof.cgi

I tried putting EOF in single quotes (print <<'EOF';) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4108672/3603374), but the error is same. Printing by this method is working in otherr files in the same directory.
I also referred [this question (Why am I getting “Can't find string terminator ”'“ anywhere before EOF at -e line 1” when I try to run a Perl one-liner on Windows?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7761057/3603374) but in that question OP is using different method to print and iam using linux(UBUNTU).

Please guide where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't get that error when running your code. Please supply a minimal example that actually produces the error.

Comment: Try adding an end-line after the EOF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Ensure that your EOF is on a single line with no spaces around it.

Use quotes to designate your terminator:

```
print <<_EOF_;
hi $$
_EOF_

print <<"_EOF_";
hi $$
_EOF_
```

Both are exactly the same (print `hi 12345` where 12345 is the process id of the current process), but the second one is more clear compared to single quotes:

```
print <<'_EOF_';
hi $$
_EOF_
```

This one will print `hi $$`, because no variable replacing is done with singles quotes.

Web-script always require a header (at least for Apache). Add this line as the first output line to get rid of the `malformed header from script` error:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: `with no spaces around it` and not like in bash with `no space in front of it `