# Perl variables order of execution

Tags: html, css, perl, cgi

I am reading some values from an SQLite database, based on a form

```
my $Fruits= $FORM{Fruits}; 
my $FruitsTable =0;
```

Once I get the values from the database, they should be stored in a variable called `my $SelectedFruits`.

```
while ( my @column = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {

    $FruitsTable = 1;

    # Within the table there is a row called Tropical which contains bananas, guaves and oranges. I want to select bananas and guaves
    my $SelectedFruits = print "<tr>
                           <td>$Tropical[0]</td>
                           <td>$Tropical[1]</td>
                     </tr>";
}
```

if they are found, a table with my selection should be printed (my problem is when the printing order):

```
if ( $FruitsTable == 1 ) {

    print "<table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Bananas</th>
                 <th>Guave</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
        <tbody>";

    $SelectedFruits;

    print "</tbody></table>";
}
```

The code exits without errors.

The problem here is that `$bananas` is printed first and the table's header and footer are printed afterwards, so the table looks crazy.

How can I print the table's header first, then the `$bananas` and then the table's footer?

Comment: You probably believe you are simplifying the code for us by using `bananas` all over the place, but in fact you have made it more awkward to read. When *every* variable contains `bananas` it doesn't provide any information, and should be deleted everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program that you write. It would have been a lot of help to you with this question

The problem is that this

```
my $bananas = print "<tr>
    <td>$happyBananas[0]</td>
    <td>$hippieBananas[1]</td>
</tr>";
```

will immediately print the table row, set the lexical variable `$bananas` to 1 (the return code of `print`) and then throw it away at the end of the loop

You want something like this instead, which accumulates the contents of the table into *non-local* variable `$bananas_rows` instead of printing it, and can then also be used as the flag to determine whether there is a table to print

Note that I've used "here documents" which rather mess up the indentation, but are more readable than bare double quotes

```
my $bananas_rows; # Don't initialise variables without a reason

while ( my @column = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {

    $bananas_rows .= <<END_HTML;
<tr>
    <td>$happyBananas[0]</td>
    <td>$hippieBananas[1]</td>
</tr>
END_HTML

}

  if ( $bananas_rows == 1 ) {

   print <<END_HTML;
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Happy Bananas</th>
      <th>Hippie Bananas</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
END_HTML

    print $bananas_rows;

    print "</tbody></table>"; 

}
```

Comment: Hi @Borodin, thanks, I'm learning! I'm having an error now "Can't find string terminator "END_HTML" anywhere before EOF" am I missing something?

Comment: @Chüngel: Make sure you don't have a space at the end of `END_HTML`

Comment: @Chüngel: Yes, there must be no spaces before or after `END_HTML`. It's a restriction that should be relaxed on near-future Perl 5 releases.

Comment: Thanks guys, double quotes mentioned in this post: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383898/getting-error-in-perl-cant-find-string-terminator-eof-anywhere-before-eof-at) + this post + the spaces solved the issue

Comment: @Chüngel: I'm pleased you have sorted it out. `print << "XXX"` is the same as `print <<<XXX` except that you may put spaces after the `<<`. `print << 'XXX'` works like a single-quoted string and won't interpolate any variables. In all cases there must be *exactly* the same spaces before and after the `XXX` as there are on the closing line, so the easiest option is none at all.